# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error on user object triggered by platform event trigger only during deployment of destructiveChanges.xml

Tags: deployment, error-messages, platform-event, locking, destructivechanges.xml

We have a platform event trigger that fires when users login.  It fires hundreds of times per week and does not throw any errors.

Three times in the past week, it has thrown an `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` error - and each time it has been when I am deploying a destructiveChanges.xml file that is removing a bunch of unused fields on contact object.

I initially ran all local tests and thought that perhaps some unit test with seeAllData = true was causing this.  The deployment failed due so next time I tried deploying while just running a single test on a trigger on the attachment object (just chose something, no specific reason).

Again, got the error. How can this be?  How can deploying a package trigger row locking?

This deployment is still running, and hopefully will succeed, but I would like to understand this, so that I can plan for it with future deployments.  I do aim for relatively off-peak times, but I do them during work hours, not on weekends, etc, and would prefer to keep it that way!

Here is the error that was logged.  Reading it again i am not sure if its a locking issue on the platform event record or the user record - the exception is on a user, but the first error indicates the platform event record.

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0051W000006omdPQAQ; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 00e40000000jut7AAA: []-0051W000006omdPQAQ-106
```

Comment: Is the field which you are trying to remove is a Custom Indexed field? Removing a Custom indexed field might be locking the object and as in community User has a lookup to Contact it may be locking user record too.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I checked all fields that were in the manifest and none are indexed field.  We also do not use communities.  Will have to monitor and if it keeps occurring will log a ticket w sf support.